# Evaluate the antiderivative of a function with a different equation depending on a bracket

Tags: integration

$$ f(x) = \begin{cases}  -1 <=> x \in (-\infty,-1]  \\
    x <=> x \in (-1,0)\\ 
    x^2 <=> x \in [ 0;\infty)   \end{cases}     $$

What have I do so far:

$$ F(x) = \begin{cases}  x +C_1 <=> x \in (-\infty,-1]  \\
    \frac{1}{2}x^2 + C_2 <=> x \in (-1,0)\\ 
    \frac{1}{3}x^3 + C_3 <=> x \in [ 0;\infty)   \end{cases}     $$

How to find C1, C2,C3?

Comment: I don't understand the symbols $>$ and $<$ here. Is your function $f$ defined at $-1$ and at $0$?

Comment: I've changed those to "$\langle$" and "$\rangle$".  (But I don't understand them either.)

Comment: @julien In Eastern Europe $"⟩"$ means the same as $"]"$, so f(x) is a continuous function. Sorry about this disambiguity. Question updated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your definition of $f$ uses the non-standard symbols $>$ and $<$; I’m going to assume that you mean

$$f(x) = \begin{cases}  -1,&\text{if } x \in (-\infty,-1] \\
    x,&\text{if }x \in (-1,0)\\ 
    x^2,&\text{if }x \in [0,\infty)\;.  \end{cases}$$

If you want $F$ to be function on all of $\Bbb R$ that has a two-sided derivative equal to $f$ everywhere, then you must at the very least choose $C_1,C_2$, and $C_3$ so that $F$ is continuous. Thus, you must choose them so that $$-1+C_1=F(-1)=\lim_{x\to-1^+}F(x)=\lim_{x\to-1^+}\left(\frac12x^2+C_2\right)=\frac12+C_2$$

and

$$C_2=\lim_{x\to0^-}\left(\frac12x^2+C_2\right)=\lim_{x\to0^-}F(x)=F(0)=C_3\;,$$

i.e., $C_3=C_2=C_1-\frac32$. You can’t pin them down to specific numerical values, however: as long as the three pieces fit together properly, you can translate the function $F$ up or down by any amount and still have a function that has $f$ as its derivative everywhere.

Answer (score 0):

In general, $C_k$'s can be arbitrary. However, if you want the anti-derivative to be continuous everywhere in the domain, then you need
\begin{align}
F(-1^-) & = F(-1^+)\\
F(0^-) & = F(0^+)
\end{align}
This will enable you to relate $C_1,C_2$ and $C_3$.